# Unable to run Selenium Webdriver script in Jenkins using Ant build.xml

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ant, continuous-integration, build.xml

I have a selenium webdriver script which i want to run in Jenkins, i created a Ant build.xml and configured it in Jenkins. My script uses Junit TestCase like below:

```
public class StartCaseJava extends TestCase {

    private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
//  Getting Date and Timestamp for Last Name
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
```

While running the run JAR step of build.xml, i am getting below error message:

```
run:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
     [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
     [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
     [java]     ... 13 more
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

Since i am new to Selenium, Java and Intellij not sure how to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

I also added junit jar in my lib folder and added path in my ant build.xml.Not sure what else i can add to my build.xml file.